# Should I use Azure Topics over Queues?

Tags: azure-servicebus-queues

I understand that Topics have the additional features of subscriptions and filters which Queues do not.
In which case, when would I absolutely need to use a queue over a topic?

For consistency, could I use a topics everywhere including as a replacement for queues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A topic is not a replacement for a queue. The combination of a topic and a **subscription** is. A topic is allowing to “replicate” the same message to multiple subscriptions. A subscription what actually holds messages. A subscription is identical to a queue in its attributes and behaviour. You could replace a queue with a topic+subscription combo if you’d like, generating 2 entities per use case instead of a single queue. Just keep in mind there’s a [finite number](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas) of entities per namespace.